# Tool for Creating List of Businesses Located in Specific Suburb

Tags: scraping

What kind of software allows you to list all businesses located in a specific suburb? I am thinking of a web scraper that will scrape a google search (of businesses in a suburb) but maybe there is another option I am not aware of?

I am looking to find out the following information:

- Business Name
- Business Type/Industry
- Business email contact

I am considering using Scrapy to crawl a google search results page. The problem is determining the business name, industry. Email addresses can easily be found by using regular expressions but industry and business name is harder. I could use Google's Prediction API to 'learn' where this information is generally located (in HTML tags - eg. `<h1>`, etc.) but I am hoping there could be existing software or even websites that can already do this. Having a website like Yelp could be another way of scraping because the business name is always located in the same location of the page.

Comment: Isn't that tool called "Yellow Pages", and searchable itself? Companies usually have phone numbers, and want to be found – so they're usually listed there.

Comment: Are you aware of our sister site, [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: Btw, Google strongly disapproves of scraping their data (or even caching it; they require you to make a fresh request every time), so, if you intend to make money with this, you may be inviting a lawsuit

Answer (score 1):

I created a GoogleMap crawler years ago called [Fantail](https://github.com/francesco1119/Fantail).

Give it a shot and let me know if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

> Having a website like Yelp could be another way of scraping because the business name is always located in the same location of the page.

You are close to the deal. I recommend you to get any [scraping software](http://scraping.pro/software-for-web-scraping/) (some of them have free options), plug in a proxy service and scrape against business directories (yellow pages, white pages, etc.). See [tips and tricks](http://scraping.pro/business-directories-scrape-tips-tricks/).